# How to access application's shared NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nstextfield, nstextview

I want to add a menu item to all text field's contextual menu. 
I can do it if I get a hold of the internal field editor of type NSTextView used by all NSTextField's through out the application. The thing is the only way I can think of getting it, is by accessing it from [window firstResponder].
Does anyone know another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more method that I can think of is subclassing the NSTextField to extend its behaviour by overriding the *menuForEvent* method.

Finally return an instance of the custom field editor using *windowWillReturnFieldEditor* method in the window delegate.